# How to use SQL server to Display column in the format 00:03:00 when the real value is 3.000

Tags: sql-server

How can i use sql select statement to display a varchar value in a column from example 3.000 to 00:03:00

[How to use SQL server to Display column in the format 00:03:00 when the real value is 3.000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTCQA.jpg)

Comment: will the duration have seconds too?

Comment: How would you convert the value `3.500`? Is it `00:03:50`, `00:03:30`, or something completly different?

Comment: @Pream No they wont. the seconds and hour part will remain 00

Comment: @BethwelLagat check if the answer works

Comment: @Pream i have checked it and even done some changes to it but still not working

Comment: @BethwelLagat give the details about the table where column with 3.000 exists(data type of the column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will help you:

```
DECLARE @UTC BIGINT
SET @UTC = 3000 //Pass your parameter here

  SELECT SUBSTRING ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @UTC % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @UTC / 1000, '')),14) ,4 ,9 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert time and DateADD to get desired result

```
select convert(time,DATEADD(MINUTE,duration,0)) from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to do it in other answers but I want to notice other thing. Storing data has some verbal or logical rules. You can convert or format it anyway but I think that the real question why are you storing that value as 3.000 if it is time or minute or something like that. If it is a time or datetime you must store it as datetime. This is the pattern else is antipattern.

Comment: Thanks for the concerns but what lead to this situation is different from your point of view. what is happening here is that i am trying to pass data from one system to another .this problem originates from one of the systems that stores minutes in varchar e.g 3.000